# in fabricjs how to give multiple function in fabric.controlsUtils actionHandler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

in fabricjs i need to give two actionHandler function  in one fabric.controlsUtils

```
objectControls.br = new fabric.Control({
    x: 0.5,
    y: 0.5,
    cursorStyleHandler: scaleStyleHandler,
    actionHandler:(()=>{widthchangeobjscale , scalingEqually}),     >>>>>>>> not working
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the original `actionHandler`. Try this:

```
function customFunc() {
  console.log("called");
}

const objControls = fabric.Object.prototype.controls;
const originalActionHandler = objControls.br.actionHandler;
objControls.br.actionHandler = (...args) => {
  customFunc();
  return originalActionHandler(...args);
};
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/fabricjs-wrap-control-action-handler-u50h32?file=/src/index.ts:329-379